# Drupal , how to render block in 'content' of a node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a common content in few pages. And I want include the content in 'content' of a node.

What I thought is use block, but I don't know how to use block in 'content' of a node. There is still some other different "div" wrapping the block, and I can't write the block in template file.
What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid rendering a block directly within the content of a page.

Instead [make a new region](http://drupal.org/node/171205#regions) directly above or below the content (depending on where you want your block to appear) and then put then block in the new region.

It is also possible to render your block directly in the template file using

```
$block = module_invoke('modulename', 'block_view', 'block_name');
print render($block);
```

This post discusses the merits of both methods: http://drupal.org/node/345361